# Am I right in thinking $\frac{x^{2}}{ax+b}$ is an improper rational expression? 

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Am I right in thinking $\dfrac{x^{2}}{ax+b}$ is an improper rational expression? If so, can someone help me figure out how to write it
 as the sum of a polynomial and proper rational expression?

I have not a clue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'll do the first few steps; here's hoping you'll catch on to what I'm doing:

$$\begin{align*}
\frac{x^2}{ax+b}&=\frac{ax^2}{a(ax+b)}\\
&=\frac{ax^2}{a(ax+b)}+\frac{bx}{a(ax+b)}-\frac{bx}{a(ax+b)}\\
&=\frac{(ax+b)x}{a(ax+b)}-\frac{bx}{a(ax+b)}\\
&=\frac{x}{a}-\frac{b}{a}\frac{x}{ax+b}\\
&=\frac{x}{a}-\frac{b}{a}\left(\frac{ax}{a(ax+b)}+\frac{b}{a(ax+b)}-\frac{b}{a(ax+b)}\right)\\
\end{align*}$$

Can you take it from here?

Comment: There is more?!?! I stopped at the 4th line!

Comment: Yes.$\phantom{}$

Comment: I hope my latex is right as I can't see it... Is it $\frac{x}{a}-\frac{b}{a}(\frac{1}{a}-\frac{b}{a(ax+b)})$

Comment: Good. Multiply it out and you're done.

Answer (score 3):

Hint: Use polynomial long division to divide $x^2$ by $ax+b$ and you will get a result of the form $(ax+b)(P)+R$. Now divide through by $ax+b$ and you have the desired form.

Comment: When in doubt, try the conjugate.

Comment: @AlexanderNikolasGruber You should expand on that and make it an answer! :)